# How to setup an ethernet connection over the Ethernet / USB HUB HAT for Raspberry Pi by waveshare on a raspberry pi zero w

Tags: pi-zero-w, ethernet, ethernet-port

I am really new at raspberry pi's and so far i have gone to chatgpt and tutorials for help but i have reached the point of desperation that i ask for the assistance of this forum.
Here is my problem:
I recently bought this pi ethernet HAT: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07T3D5MQ6/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=A2FQD9ZIAONBLW&psc=1
but i have no idea how to set it up and/or test how it works. Please remember i am a novice at this and will need **clear** instructions on how.
Many thanks,
Therandomspoon

Comment: You have bought a device without specifications or apparently instructions on use. It is unlikely anyone on this site has one. Have you plugged it into the Pi and examined what interfaces it exposes? If it exposes a Ethernet interface it should be obvious and `dhcpcd` should automatically configure from your router. Frankly for the price you could have purchased a Pi with superior performance and documented interfaces . (The Pi Zero W is a very basic computer.)

Answer (score 0):

Waveshare have a [wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/ETH/USB_HUB_HAT) which documents the use of this [USB and Ethernet hat](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/ETH/USB_HUB_HAT), once it is attached to the pi zero, make sure you power the pi through the micro usb connector on the hat, not the power connector on the pi zero.

The /boot/config.txt needs the following:

```
[HAT]
# Waveshare
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host
```

and the /boot/cmdline.txt needs the following addition:

```
module-load=dwc2,g_ether
```

Then the USB and Ethernet Hat should work.